Node.js & Next.js Can't resolve '@vercel/turbopack-ecmascript-runtime/dev/client/hmr-client.ts' Error
I'm making a small portfolio on Next.js and wanna add an opportunity to send emails to me, so I'm using the nodemailer, but it shows
an error whenever the site starts:
Module not found: Can't resolve '@vercel/turbopack-ecmascript-runtime/dev/client/hmr-client.ts'

The file tree
sendEmail.js
"use server"

import nodemailer from "nodemailer"

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "gmail",
    port: 300,
    secure: false, // Use `true` for port 465, `false` for all other ports
    auth: {
      user: "...",
      pass: "...",
    },
  });
  
  // async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
  export default async function sendEmail() {
    // send mail with defined transport object
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: '"Job Portfolio" <>', // sender address
      to: "bar@example.com, baz@example.com", // list of receivers
      subject: "Job", // Subject line
      text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
      html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
    });
  
    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <d786aa62-4e0a-070a-47ed-0b0666549519@ethereal.email>
  }
  

Contact.tsx:
"use client"

import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import sendEmail from '@/pages/api/sendEmail.js';

const Contact = () => {

  const[email, setEmail] = useState('');


  return (

  

        <form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
   

            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email}/>
..
               
          </form>


  )
}

export default Contact

I suppose the problem is related to the use of 'use client' and 'use server'. I've tried to change them, but still not working.
The dependency of nodemailer is included and saved in the package.json file.

try this https://medium.com/@jamesowen.dev/how-to-send-email-forms-using-next-js-13-with-nodemailer-1bc9e5dd5e80
